# how add custom attributes to cart.py

Tags: python, django

I am writing an electronic prescribing module that permits a user to select a child user to attach to an order. The system works like a shopping cart, where products are added to the cart.

The User is related to the Clinic.  The Practitioner is related to their own user but also is a foreign key to the Clinic.

In the cart I want to associate the child user to the product purchased.  The use case is that either the Practitioner, or the Clinic may be logged in to place an order.

The cart.html page needs to be a form which permits the selection of a Practitioner user which is associated with the Clinic.

I am just struggling to get my head around how I add custom attributes to the cart after the product has been selected.
Please help!

***MODELS.PY***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils import timezone
from Product.models import Product
import uuid
import datetime
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import random

class Clinic(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(ClinicGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('clinic_name',)
        verbose_name = ('Clinic')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Clinics')

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.clinic_name )

class Practitioner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    prescriber_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('last_name',)
        verbose_name = ('Vet')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Vets')
    


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.last_name) + " " + str(self.first_name)
```

***CART.PY***

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from Product.models import Product

#from coupons.models import Coupon


class Cart(object):

   def __init__(self, request):
       """
       Initialize the cart.
       """
       self.user = request.user
       self.session = request.session
       cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
       if not cart:
           # save an empty cart in the session
           cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
       self.cart = cart
       # store current applied coupon
       self.coupon_id = self.session.get('coupon_id')

   def __len__(self):
       """
       Count all items in the cart.
       """
       return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

   def __iter__(self):
       """
       Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products from the database.
       """
       product_ids = self.cart.keys()
       # get the product objects and add them to the cart
       products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
       for product in products:
           self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

       for item in self.cart.values():
           item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
           item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
           yield item

   def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
       """
       Add a product to the cart or update its quantity.
       """
       product_id = str(product.id)
       if product_id not in self.cart:
           self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
       if update_quantity:
           self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
       else:
           self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
       self.save()

   def remove(self, product):
       """
       Remove a product from the cart.
       """
       product_id = str(product.id)
       if product_id in self.cart:
           del self.cart[product_id]
           self.save()

   def save(self):
       # update the session cart
       self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
       # mark the session as "modified" to make sure it is saved
       self.session.modified = True

   def clear(self):
       # empty cart
       self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
       self.session.modified = True

   #@property
   #def coupon(self):
   #    if self.coupon_id:
    #       return Coupon.objects.get(id=self.coupon_id)
   #    return None

   def get_total_price(self):
       return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

   def get_discount(self):
       if self.coupon:
           return (self.coupon.discount / Decimal('100')) * self.get_total_price()
       return Decimal('0')

   def get_total_price_after_discount(self):
       return self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount()
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from Product.models import Product

#from coupons.models import Coupon


class Cart(object):

   def __init__(self, request):
       """
       Initialize the cart.
       """
       self.user = request.user
       self.session = request.session
       cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
       if not cart:
           # save an empty cart in the session
           cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
       self.cart = cart
       # store current applied coupon
       self.coupon_id = self.session.get('coupon_id')

   def __len__(self):
       """
       Count all items in the cart.
       """
       return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

   def __iter__(self):
       """
       Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products from the database.
       """
       product_ids = self.cart.keys()
       # get the product objects and add them to the cart
       products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
       for product in products:
           self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

       for item in self.cart.values():
           item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
           item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
           yield item

   def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
       """
       Add a product to the cart or update its quantity.
       """
       product_id = str(product.id)
       if product_id not in self.cart:
           self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,
                                     'price': str(product.price)}
       if update_quantity:
           self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
       else:
           self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
       self.save()

   def remove(self, product):
       """
       Remove a product from the cart.
       """
       product_id = str(product.id)
       if product_id in self.cart:
           del self.cart[product_id]
           self.save()

   def save(self):
       # update the session cart
       self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
       # mark the session as "modified" to make sure it is saved
       self.session.modified = True

   def clear(self):
       # empty cart
       self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
       self.session.modified = True

   #@property
   #def coupon(self):
   #    if self.coupon_id:
    #       return Coupon.objects.get(id=self.coupon_id)
   #    return None

   def get_total_price(self):
       return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

   def get_discount(self):
       if self.coupon:
           return (self.coupon.discount / Decimal('100')) * self.get_total_price()
       return Decimal('0')

   def get_total_price_after_discount(self):
       return self.get_total_price() - self.get_discount()
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from users.models import Practitioner


PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 21)]


class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
                                      coerce=int,
                                      label=_('Quantity'))
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                initial=False,
                                widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

**Views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from Product.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm
#from coupons.forms import CouponApplyForm
#from shop.recommender import Recommender


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product,
                 quantity=cd['quantity'],
                 update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')

def add_practitioner(request, prescriber_id):
    cart=Cart(request)

def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'],
                                                                   'update': True})
    #coupon_apply_form = CouponApplyForm()

    #r = Recommender()
    #cart_products = [item['product'] for item in cart]
    #recommended_products = r.suggest_products_for(cart_products, max_results=4)

    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

**DETAIL.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
   <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
  <h1>Your shopping cart  </h1>
  {{ form }}
  <table class="cart">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Unit price</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for item in cart %}
        {% with product=item.product %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}
                {% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
              </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            <td>
  <form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
    {{ item.update_quantity_form.override }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
</td>

            <td>
              <form action="{% url "cart:cart_remove" product.id %}" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Remove">
                {% csrf_token %}
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="num">${{ item.price }}</td>
            <td class="num">${{ item.total_price }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
      <tr class="total">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="num">${{ cart.get_total_price }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
   <div class="col-6 col-md-4">.col-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <p class="text-right">
      <a href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}" class="button
      light">Continue shopping</a>
  <a href="{% url 'orders:order_create' %}" class="button">
    Checkout
  </a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: if the child is a user of the application, how about having a dropdown in the form populated with children, or some other mechanism such as an input for something unique about a child if they are too many (email?). and then post the form with the child's attribute such that in the add method of cart.py you add a variable for the child in self.cart?

Comment: That is a good solution.  The user(practitioner) will be a child of the parent(clinic) and all associated children should be obtainable from the parent(clinic) model